# Tried to implement List comprehension in Python 3.7x

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Tried to implement List comprehension in Python 3.7x with following example

```
a_list = [1, ‘4’, 9, ‘a’, 0, 4]
squared_ints = [ e**2 for e in a_list if type(e) == types.IntType ]
```

However it fails with the below error

> NameError: name 'types' is not defined

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Why did you expect `types` to be defined?

Answer (score 3):

First off, the `NameError` is because you need to import the `types` module before you can use it:

```
import types
```

However, this still won't work since `types.IntType` doesn't exist in Python 3; `int` is already available as a built-in so it's unnecessary.

Finally, you generally shouldn't do type comparisons using equality; prefer [`isinstance`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance) checks instead:

```
a_list = [1, '4', 9, 'a', 0, 4]
squared_ints = [ e**2 for e in a_list if isinstance(e, int)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it says, `types` is not defined, you better search for what class you are referencing to.

While, on the other hand, a different way to do this is:

```
a_list = [1, ‘4’, 9, ‘a’, 0, 4]
squared_ints = [ e**2 for e in a_list if type(e) == int ]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `types.IntType`, you can try `type(e) == int`

```
squared_ints = [ e**2 for e in a_list if type(e) == int ]
```

For built-in data types you can call them as-is (ie, int, str, dict, list, tuple, set etc)